# How to display a progress bar that shows over-achievement (Above 100%) in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a progress bar that displays a percentage over 100% in a different color to give an idea that an over-achievement has occurred. How can this be done in HTML/CSS?

The following works well for a progress bar that will display a percentage up to 100%

```
<div id="progressbar">
  <div></div>
</div>

#progressbar {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 13px; /* (height of inner div) / 2 + padding */
  padding: 3px;
}

#progressbar div {
   background-color: orange;
   width: 40%; /* Adjust with JavaScript */
   height: 20px;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This site gives you  an idea: http://yensdesign.com/2008/11/how-to-create-a-stylish-loading-bar-as-gmail-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/qTmGE/1/

Pardon my usage of jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Pure CSS PROGRESS BAR -- [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/saf8Q/)

Comment: Using unstandardized webkit-properties. I don't think that's favorable.

Comment: read question carefully @perpetual_dream wants css progress bar

Comment: Mine is as pure CSS as yours is (javascript is just a helper function to change the value more easily), there's no need to be snarky about it.